# Liferay portal to extract portlet as different web application

Tags: liferay

I am new to Liferay portal. Is there any possibility within Liferay portal to extract portlet as different web application?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin portlets are typically deployed as a separate web application. If you're asking about Liferay's core portlets: No, they are contained in Liferay. All of the plugins are downloaded separately and installed as a different web application

Answer (score 0):

If you want share your portlet, Liferay has some features.

Drag and drop your portlet in page and then click on configuration icon.
In the popup select `Sharing` tab

[image]

You can choose your preferred sharing mode (embedded javascript, facebook,.).
When you share a portlet, be careful about permission settings otherwise users will not be able to view it.

Another chance is to use porltet url, see [FriendlyUrlMapper wiki](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper)

This is an example for portlet HelloWorld in /web/guest/home page

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_p_id=helloWorld_WAR_HelloWorld&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1
```